# Tensorflow TextVectorization adapt() -- checking the produced vocabulary

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, character-encoding, embedding

A text `TextVectorization` layer is used for word encoding, and the typical workflow calls the `adapt()` method

> Next, you will call adapt to fit the state of the preprocessing layer
> to the dataset.
> This will cause the model to build an index of strings to integers.

(https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/text_classification)

or

> If desired, the user can call this layer's adapt() method on a
> dataset. When this layer is adapted, it will analyze the dataset,
> determine the frequency of individual string values, and create a
> 'vocabulary' from them.

(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/TextVectorization#adapt)

What is precisely the result of the `adapt()` operation, and how to check concretely the content of the created vocabulary?

A small piece of my code

```
seq_length = 100
vocab_size=50000

vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(
    max_tokens=vocab_size,
    output_mode='int',
    output_sequence_length=seq_length)

# build the vocabulary
vectorize_layer.adapt(text_ds)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`layer.get_vocabulary()` does this:

```
>>>data = tf.constant([["a", "c", "d"], ["d", "z", "b"]])
>>>layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup()
>>>layer.adapt(data)
>>>layer.get_vocabulary()

['[UNK]', 'd', 'z', 'c', 'b', 'a']
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/StringLookup